# Unary Rpc call using asynchronous stub in Grpc Java

Tags: java, grpc, grpc-java

I am new to gRPC and was looking for some example for unary RPC call using async stub, didn't found any. I tried to write my own HelloWorld type service, where client sends a simple text and server reply a simple text which is working with blockingStub and when i created a StreamObserver object and used async stub, it is showing error

`CANCELLED: io.grpc.Context was cancelled without error`.

Please provide a basic example (in java) how unary rpc works with async stub and what client and server will code will be needed.

Comment: Check this example - http://www.vinsguru.com/grpc-unary-api-service-implementation/

Comment: Hey, welcome to SO! Can you paste your code? Don't be afraid to paste a lot! And indent them by 4 spaces so they format as code. (Or surround them like this: \`\`\`code\`\`\`.)